# SSRS expression seems to be rounding the decimal amount when it sets the value into the variable

Tags: reporting-services, expression

My expression is taking a dollar amount from the database and storing it into a variable or taking the variable and adding a dollar amount to it before updating the variable based on some other fields criteria, and then displaying the variable in the textbox.
It seems that the variable is being rounded to the whole number but still displaying two decimal points. How to keep variable from being rounded?
`=IF(Fields!APBAC_AMOUNT.Value > 0 And Fields!APBAC_TYPE.Value = "AP" Or Fields!APBAC_TYPE.Value = "BD",  Variables!rptBalance.setValue(Variables!rptBalance.Value + Fields!AMOUNTRECEIVED.Value) And Variables!rptBalance.Value, Variables!rptBalance.setValue(Fields!APBAC_BALANCE.Value) AND Fields!APBAC_BALANCE.Value)`

Comment: In your dataset, just CAST(???  AS Decimal(10,2)) for all values (??? being the values).  Decimal (p,s)
 p (precision):- Specifies the maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point.

s (scale):- Specifies the maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: When I bring in the value from the dataset it displays correctly, it's only when I write the value to the variable and then display the variable that it's getting rounded.

Comment: you can change the format of the variable by selecting it, go to the properties and down to format. change it P2. You can also format in the expression field using =Format(Fields!XXXXX.Value, "F2")